# My Custom drupal 8 module does not shown in modules list

Tags: 8, .info

I'm developing my first drupal 8 module, a custom migration module, the `info.yml` file is written as follow :

```
name : Drupal Center Custom Migrate
description : This module provides custom migration configuration and plugins to migrate my custom site from drupal 6.
type : module
core : 8.x

package : Custom migrate
dependencies :
  - migrate
  - migrate_plus
  - migrate_tools
  - migrate_upgrade
  - migrate_drupal
```

The above code is saved as `dc_custom_migrate.info.yml` . This module also provides some config migration file and some custom source plugins.

The problem is my custom module is not shown up in modules list.

I can't figure it up where am I doing wrong!!!

PS. I'm developing in windows 10 environment and using [Aquia Dev Desktop 2](https://dev.acquia.com/downloads) as web service simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the identifiers and colons:

```
name: Drupal Center Custom Migrate
description: This module provides custom migration configuration and plugins to migrate my custom site from drupal 6.
type: module
core: 8.x

package: Custom migrate
dependencies:
  - migrate
  - migrate_plus
  - migrate_tools
  - migrate_upgrade
  - migrate_drupal
```

Then it'll work.

See the [YAML rules](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/yaml/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should have change all my migration configuration files as well.